# Algorithm to find the closest time

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a list of DateTime values with dates that contain hours and minutes:

```
List<DateTime> times = times = new List<DateTime>()
{
    new DateTime(2019, 01, 01, 17, 00, 00),
    new DateTime(2019, 01, 01, 18, 45, 00),
    new DateTime(2019, 01, 01, 19, 00, 00),
    new DateTime(2019, 01, 01, 19, 30, 00),
    new DateTime(2019, 01, 01, 22, 30, 00)
};

DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
```

I put them all in a ComboBox, and I want to make some sort of algorithm so when I load my form, it will check for the current time and find the closest value to the current time and select the ComboBox item that contains that hour.

How can I achieve this? I tried to loop through them all and check for the least hour, but that doesn't seem to work. Is there a smarter way to do it?

For example: If the current time is 17:32, it will choose 17:00, because that's the closest. But, if the current time is 18:20, it will choose 18:45 and so on.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far..?

Comment: Since the list is ordered you should be able to use a binary search.

Answer (score 6):

Compare to the `Ticks` property of `DateTime` ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks?view=netframework-4.8)). It can be seen as a linear representation of the whole date and timestamp and is sortable.

Do something like

```
comboBox.SelectedItem = times.OrderBy(t => Math.Abs(t.Ticks - current.Ticks)).First()
```

Comment: Make it an extension method: `public static DateTime MinDifference(this DateTime dateTime, IEnumerable<DateTime> values) => values.OrderBy(t => Math.Abs(t.Ticks - dateTime.Ticks)).First();` which can be used as: `var minDiff = DateTime.Now.MinDifference(times);`

Comment: in TS:

`selectedTime = [...this.times].sort((timeA, timeB) => (Math.abs(moment(timeA.start).unix() - now.unix()) - Math.abs(moment(timeB.start).unix() - now.unix())))[0]
`

Answer (score 2):

You could take the difference with DateTime.Now for all your datetimes, order by this difference and take the first result.

```
times.OrderBy(m => Math.Abs((DateTime.Now - m).TotalMilliseconds)).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to select an instance of `DateTime` which minimizes the temporal distance to the current time. You could use an extension method for `IEnumerable<T>` to do that as follows.

```
public static T ArgMin<T, R>(T t1, T t2, Func<T, R> f)
                where R : IComparable<R>
{
    return f(t1).CompareTo(f(t2)) > 0 ? t2 : t1;
}

public static T ArgMin<T, R>(this IEnumerable<T> Sequence, Func<T, R> f)
                where R : IComparable<R>
{
    return Sequence.Aggregate((t1, t2) => ArgMin<T, R>(t1, t2, f));
}

var iNow = DateTime.Now;
var iResult = times.ArgMin(iTime => Math.Abs((iTime - iNow).Ticks));
```

Although very generic, this implementation does not involve any sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `ArgMax` which is not implemented in standard *Linq*, but can be emulated via `Aggreagte`

```
  List<DateTime> times = new List<DateTime>() {
    new DateTime(2019, 01, 01, 17, 00, 00),
    new DateTime(2019, 01, 01, 18, 45, 00),
    new DateTime(2019, 01, 01, 19, 00, 00),
    new DateTime(2019, 01, 01, 19, 30, 00),
    new DateTime(2019, 01, 01, 22, 30, 00),
  };

  DateTime toFind = new DateTime(2019, 5, 8, 18, 20, 0);

  var closestTime = times
    .Aggregate((best, item) => Math.Abs((item.TimeOfDay - toFind.TimeOfDay).Ticks) < 
                               Math.Abs((best.TimeOfDay - toFind.TimeOfDay).Ticks) 
       ? item 
       : best);
```

Please, note, that if we should find the closest *time*, we have to get rid of date part - `TimeOfDay`. If date part should be count, just remove `TimeOfDay` -

```
  var closestDateAndTime = times
    .Aggregate((best, item) => Math.Abs((item - toFind).Ticks) < 
                               Math.Abs((best - toFind).Ticks) 
       ? item 
       : best);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use MoreLinq's [`MinBy`](https://morelinq.github.io/2.0/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_MinBy__2_1.htm):

```
var actualNow = DateTime.Now;
// set `current` up however you need it
var current = new DateTime(2019, 01, 01, actualNow.Hour, actualNow.Minute, actualNow.Minute, actualNow.Millisecond); // set this up however you need it
var min = times.MinBy(z => Math.Abs((current - z).Ticks)).First();
```

It avoids the memory pressure of the `OrderBy` based solutions (since it avoids allocating a list to store the entire set of `times`).

Note you may want to check whether `times` is empty before using this (or other) solutions. If you don't wish to do that, consider using:

```
var min = times.MinBy(z => Math.Abs((current - z).Ticks)).Cast<DateTime?>().FirstOrDefault();
```

which will return `null` (rather than `default(DateTime)`, or throw an exception) if `times` is empty.